# Alternate way of returning data from fetch using useEffect inside a callback

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My objective of this code is to receive the variable 'city' from a separate function called Create, pass in the parameter for my API request to [https://goweather.herokuapp.com/weather/${city}](https://goweather.herokuapp.com/weather/$%7Bcity%7D), and receive the weather data according to the city I have inputted.

I made a separate function called Create using onCreate, I received the value of 'city', inputted by the user.
I understood that fetching data is asynchronous, so I tried to use useEffect to save the data I received from my API request via states, using
`const [target, setTarget] = useState();`
However, it is impossible to use useEffect inside a callback function, and this is the error message React gave me.
[image: Error]

```
if (mode === 'CREATE') {
  content = <Create onCreate = {(city) => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://goweather.herokuapp.com/weather/${city}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setTarget(data);
          console.log(data);
        })
    }, []);
    console.log('raw data: ', target);
  }}></Create>
}
```

I tried to wrap around my head and think of any other possibility I could make this happen, but I cannot think of a way to use asynchronous and synchronous functions at the same time, especially because it has been a few days since I started React. What are some ways I could possibly fix this issue?

Removing useEffect will do nothing to my original 'target' variable because there is a delay of fetching a request, and target will just be assigned to undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to simply delete the `useEffect`, and fetch the data directly in the `onCreate` callback. `useEffect` is for when you need to have the act of rendering trigger some side effect. But you aren't trying to fetch data as a result of rendering, but rather when this onCreate callback happens, so no useEffect is needed.

```
<Create onCreate = {(city) => {
  fetch(`https://goweather.herokuapp.com/weather/${city}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setTarget(data);
      console.log(data);
    })
}}></Create>
```

Now in your example, you did have a log statement like `console.log('raw data: ', target);`. That's only ever going to log out the old value. `target` is a local `const`, which is basically a snapshot of what the state was on the last render. Calling `setTarget` will not change the value in `target`, it just asks react to rerender the component. When that render happens a new local variable will be created with the new state, but code from the previous render has no access to that.

If you want to use the new value, you have that in the variable named `data`, so where you do `console.log(data)`, you can add any other code you like that needs to use it.

```
.then((data) => {
  setTarget(data);
  console.log(data);
  // Do anything you like with data
})
```